# What is the difference between a dacpac with extractAllTableData flag and a bacpac?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'd like to backup a database in SSMS and restore it to a different server on a VM. I've exported dbs to bacpacs but keep hitting roadblocks like users having windows authentication or errors validating elements.

I've recently noticed that a dacpac with the extraAllTableData set to true might accomplish a similar thing. I know that bacpacs are tailored for Azure Sql Servers but are there any other differences between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DACPAC contains only schema information only.
BACPAC contains both schema and data. It also contains the security.

If you go with ExtractAllTableData option, in addition to schema, user data is also extracted. But, still permissions are not extracted.

> /p:   ExtractAllTableData=(BOOLEAN)   Indicates whether data from all user
> tables is extracted. If 'true', data from all user tables is
> extracted, and you cannot specify individual user tables for
> extracting data. If 'false', specify one or more user tables to
> extract data from.